# place a JLabel(s) at a desired location giving its coordinates

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel, keylistener

I have a `JPanel` in which I need to add bunch of `JLabel`s at a required coordinates. These `JLabel`s will have key Listeners assigned to them that will determine new position using arrow keys.

To be more specific I know how to do it when there is only one `JLabel` but whenever I put a more of them the things mess up. while I use arrow key the first `JLabel` moves but all other `JLabel` disappears.

Can Anyone give me some hints to write a method to put a `JLabel` in a specific coordinate and also move them using arrow key later without making other `JLabel`s dissapear?

Huge Thanks in Advance

Comment: I think, you need to post some relevant code snippets.

Comment: Post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Try adding all your labels in a List and inside the arrow keys event cicle throught the list and move them. If you want to move every single label by his own you should implement some sort of "select" method to know which one to move. Posting the relevant parts of your code could help us ... helping you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using JDesktopPane or JLayeredPane, it works the same as the JPanels, but you won't use layouts, with these you will use Bounds, you always have to set the bound of a jlabel like this.

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello");
label.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 20);
//label.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
pane.add(label)
```

if you need to move that label, then you can use something like

```
int xx = label.getBounds().getX();
int yy = label.getBounds().getY();
int ww = label.getBounds().getWidth();
int hh = label.getBounds().getHeight();

//to the right 10 units
xx+=10;
label.setBounds( xx, yy, ww, hh );
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using `repaint()` to update the UI. Btw, upon which component you are calling `repaint()`?

Comment: What does `SwingWorker` have to do with what the OP wants? :)

Comment: Adjusted, accordingly. I was thinking that something is also happening on the UI, but then realised that it's just like a canvas to design interface.

Comment: I am not using repaint() Actually I did my project on netbeans so I just wrote the methode to move a JLabel. which works fine until I add another JLabel.